# How to get ZeroMQ Timestamp?

Tags: c++, time, zeromq

I'm writing a C++/ZMQ script that has a subscriber getting data from a publisher run by a separate script. I can't edit the publisher code, and I need to get the time that the ZeroMQ subscriber receives a message.

Basically, I have:

```
void *zmq_subscriber_ = zmq_socket( context, ZMQ_SUB );
zmq_setsockopt( zmq_subscriber_, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, NULL, 0 );

while ( ( zmq_msg_recv( &msg, zmq_subscriber_, ZMQ_DONTWAIT ) ) < 0 )
{ usleep( 1000 ); }
```

I need to know when the subscriber receives the message. Is there a way to get this information from ZeroMQ? Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: "I need to know". Who or what is I there? You as person? Just have the subscriber print out a time when it gets a message.The publisher? For that the subscriber has to send an ACK back. Can't be done with just PUB/SUB. The subscriber? Simply read out the time when you get a message.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You may already know, there is a Zero-knowledge about when a msg has actually arrived "into" the `Context()`-domain of control, as the "outer"-world just asynchronously "asks" the `Context()`-internal-service, whether there is a new message to retrieve from queue, without knowing, how long that piece of data has been already waiting there for its turn to later get fetched & delivered to the outer-world. So the outer code may record a timestamp, but that refers only about a moment, when outer world has tried to learn & finally indeed has learnt a message can be `.recv()`'d

Comment: @user3666197 True. But if you poll for messages the difference between a message arriving and poll returning is usually negible.

Comment: Not necessarily, Sir. Even if one carefully `.poll()`-s in a non-blocking mode, there are still principal uncertainties ( blind-spots ), how long did that actually take, before your "current" thread did get a CPU-scheduler time-slot for execution, and that is not under one's control, and gets worse under load, when your priority-driven turn could get way back in the CPU-scheduler code-execution queue + the same valid for the respective `Context()`-s IO-thread, so a chain of principally uncoordinated async events just grows the E2E-delivery uncertainty and the principal jitter of latency skews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there a way to **get this information from ZeroMQ ?***

Fortunately not directly from ZeroMQ API as-is ( in 2018/Q2 ).

---

### Any options?

Given a coarse TimeDOMAIN resolution is fine, just store a Timestamp every time your code re-loops the `while(){...; <here> }` codeblock. This approach has a blind-spot of about the `usleep()`-duration - a latency, where a more precise moment of the receipt is undecideable.

Given this does not suffice, start using a non-blocking mode of a `Poller.poll()` method, and reduce any such latency to a level your intent can work with. Once handle an *almost*-zero-latency `.poll()` having zero-wait duration "inside" a `Poller.poll()` plus avoid spending any such `usleep()` so as to minimise the blind-spot.

If in an extreme need, refactor the code and introduce a new (private) API extension, so as to read such detail from `Context()`-instance internal state-registers. This would get you closer, if not the closest, to the actual moment of a message arrival into the hands of the **`SUB`**-side `Context()`'s internal processing.

Comment: @T-Boone Glad it helped, indeed. Welcome to the StackOverflow Community.